# Java doesn't have any import aliasing mechanisms, and I have two import statements with the same name

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium for web interaction and I need to use      `import com.google.common.io.Files` for it to work. However, I also need to use `import java.nio.file.Files;` for some files that I work with. I don't know what to do because java doesn't allow for import aliasing as far as I can tell. Is there any way to cope with this? Let me know if I need to provide any other details

The "import java.nio.file.Files:" is only used for the ".readString(Path)" So if there is another way to get the contents of a file as a string from a "Path" please let me know.

The `import java.nio.file.Files;` is also used only inside a method if there is any weird obscure way to only import for the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can import one File class to access directly by its name. Furthermore you can access your second File class by its full qualified name. e.g.

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;

...
Files f = new Files()
f.yxz();
java.nio.file.Files a = new java.nio.file.Files()
a.abc()
```

Comment: One of the things I tried was "var = java.nio.file.Files.readString(Path);" instead of importing it. But it still causes issues with the other Files class, what am i doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to import one and use the fully qualified name for the other.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;

MyClass {
    Files.list(...); //  refers to Files from java.nio

    com.google.common.io.Files.getFileExtension(...)
}
```

Comment: One of the things I tried was "var = java.nio.file.Files.readString(Path);" instead of importing it. But it still causes issues with the other Files class, what am i doing wrong with this?

Comment: @worldHello Without seeing your code and knowing what the "issues with the other Files class" are, it's impossible to answer.